# How to deal with discontinous problem with numerical method?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, parabolic-pde, finite-differences

I would like to consider how to deal with the indicator function in a PDE. For example, for the PME with =5, the initial condition is the two-Box solution with the same height, namely
$$
u_0(x)= 1 \text { if } x \in(-3.7,-0.7) \cup(0.7,3.7); u_0(x) = 0 \text { otherwise }
$$
Now, my question is whether it is possible to approximate this function using the finite difference method. I am aware that the finite difference method may overlook the points of discontinuity. Therefore, I am interested in understanding the general approach to numerically handle such problems. I would appreciate it if you could help me gain a better understanding of the finite difference method.

Comment: What is the PME with $m=5$? If it has a smoothing effect like the diffusion equation, your finite difference implementation should have no difficulties using a discontinuous initial condition.